# How to Write File Name Specific Snippets Using UltiSnips or Otherwise

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I have been using the plugin called Ultisnips and it is great.

But I am looking for the following feature.

Suppose I have two files `history.tex` and `geography.tex` which I edit regularly.

I want to have snippets for each of them but I want them to be independent of each other. What I mean by this is that if I am working on `history.tex`, a snippet named `samplesnip` serves some purpose while when I am working on `geography.tex` the snippet named `samplesnip` serves a completely different purpose.

Right now what I have is a file named `tex.snippets` where all my snippets for tex files go. So I do not have the kind of flexibility that I want.

Comment: Really, the easiest way would be to slightly rename a snippet (or both) - if they are so specialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `UltiSnipsAddFiletypes`. As the [docs](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L218) say:

> The UltiSnipsAddFiletypes command allows for explicit merging of other
>   snippet filetypes for the current buffer. For example, if you edit a
>   .rst file but also want the Lua snippets to be available you can issue
>   the command >
>
> :UltiSnipsAddFiletypes rst.lua

To automatically set the filetype when you edit a file, add the following to your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead history.tex UltiSnipsAddFiletypes history.tex
```

Note that as stated in `:help 'filetype'`, vim natively supports the idea of dotted filetypes, so you could change the filetype to history.tex to do custom filetype plugins, syntax, and more.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to use python interpolation in your snippet, but I think the above is more in line with what you want.